# Click interface Clarification (Entry-Level)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to create a graph editor using WinForms.

I have a picture box, whenever I click on it the program draws a vertex by creating a label about 15px in size where I store a string, the location, etc.

I can draw the edges by drawing lines from location to location, but I need other boxes to do this, I wonder if there is a way to do this purely by touch (with the mouse cursor).

I need some kind of object that if clicked will start an event that will draw an edge up to the vertex I click next. I considered adding little picture boxes instead of labels, but the labels are convenient for storing the name of the vertexes, also I think adding both a label and an other box in the same position may hide one of the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the x and y coordinate's of the mouse on a user controls click event.
I would store the coordinate's of the last point you clicked on outside of the mouse click event and then draw a line from the last point to the new point.

```
lastPoint = null;
private void userControl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {

  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    Point newPoint = e.Location;
    if(lastPoint != null)
    {
      drawLine(lastPoint, newPoint);
    }
    lastPoint = newPoint;

  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: everything helps. I already have a list with my labels (and their locations), what I'm trying to do is: after the labels are in place, click on them again and have a line go exactly from one label location to the other,

Comment: So let me get this straight you already have labels defined on your form. But you want to have the uses select label pairs in which there will be a line joining. For example if you had 4 labels on the form say: A, B, C, D the user could click A, D then B,D then DC which would draw three lines going from A to D, B to D and D to C?

Comment: that's what I want to do. I'm not sure if it's possible, maybe labels aren't the right tool for this..

Comment: I could decide that I will draw A and connect it to B and then to C with three clicks, but what if I then want to connect D and A or have a vertex that's connected to only another one while the graph "proceeds"?

Comment: What i would do in this case is to store a list of Tuple's which hold the coordinate pairs. In a separate function i would iterate over each of the coordinate pairs in the list and draw a line for each.  To create the list:             List<Tuple<Point, Point>> pointPairs = new List<Tuple<Point, Point>>(); to add points to the list: 
            Point firstPoint = new Point(10, 20);
            Point secondPoint = new Point(30, 60);
            pointPairs.Add(new Tuple<Point, Point>(firstPoint, secondPoint));

Comment: Then i would add a function which draws all the lines stored in the list:         public void DrawLines()
        {
            foreach(var pointPair in pointPairs)
            {
                DrawLine(pointPair.Item1, pointPair.Item2);
            }
        }

Comment: I was thinking of taking inspiration form Mathlab and create a label list for the vertexes and three string or int lists for start points, end points and distances (synchronized by a common index). The problem is getting the mouse input for the setting up of the edges...

Comment: I can always do it with other boxes for the parameters and a big button to generate the edge, but liked the idea of the "touch" experience.